# Placing an image in a specific region of another image

Tags: image-processing

Here is an oval, and a box

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

The goal is to place the oval inside the green box.

If you imagine the green box on the bottom to be your bounds, the top image can be placed anywhere inside the green box. The oval cannot flow outside of the green box.

Input is just the two images and I'm told to "put the red oval in the green box." If it is not possible (eg: the oval is too big), nothing happens.

It is trivial to do it by hand in a image editor: just drag the top image over the green box and make sure it doesn't flow out the sides.

How should this problem be approached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of ways of doing this and choosing one depends on problem constraints.  In the simplest case, if you know the exact colours of the red, blue, and green, and know that none of the shapes are rotated the solution is simple.  First binarize the image so that only one object is separated (oval or rectangle) then find the highest,lowest,leftmost,and rightmost point for that object.  Repeat for the other object.  That information will tell you if the ellipse can fit in the rectangle.

If those constraints are too rigid, then you will probably want to use [blob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection) detection.  Perhaps [cvblob](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/) or [cvblobslib](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib/).  They can handle the much more general case of varying colours and orientations.